# How do I treat an API that requires an InputEvent in a Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am having a public API that I want to use and in this API there is a method that requires an [InputEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html) (because its commonly used). I want to use this API from a code that is called via a socket connection and thus doesn't have a InputEvent.

In my current situation its [ActionManager.tryToExecute()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/9.0.4/com/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ActionManager.java#ActionManager.tryToExecute%28com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction,java.awt.event.InputEvent,java.awt.Component,java.lang.String,boolean%29) from the IntelliJ Idea SDK.

As far as I can tell I can not simply instantiate a InputEvent. Am I wrong about this?
Do I need to search another API that doesn't require a InputEvent?

Comment: Your question needs some work. IntelliJ is an IDE, not an API. We need to know what API you are trying to work with. Include a sample of the code you are having issues with.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I wanted to keep the question general, in case other persons have API's that want to be satisfied with an InputEvent.

Comment: Well as it stands now its impossible to even tell which InputEvent class you are referring too. My guess would be its the [standard one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html) from Java AWT. But it could be a third party class for all the information given.

Comment: I tried to incorporate your suggestions. I hope its clearer understandable now.